# Is it possible to cancel or forcibly expire an AAD B2C invite link?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an app that uses AAD B2C user management. Users can send invite links via email. The invite link has an expiry of 7 days according to the JWT config. We store the invitation as application data.

Because registration is handled within the policy it has no visibility of invitation state. However, I want to give existing users the ability to cancel an invite, thereby preventing the invitee from completing the policy and signing up.

Similarly, the policy only checks for email conflicts after the form has been submitted, despite already being served with the invited email. Is it possible to have the policy check the validity of the invited email before it serves the form?

```xml
<!--Sample: Set input the ReadOnlyEmail claim type to prefilled the email address-->
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
```

So my point is: what do I need to do to get the policy to validate the invite link before it gets served? I haven't found anything via Google so apologies if this is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is add an extension attribute to B2C that could be set via Graph API e.g. a PS script.

This would be set by the user on the invitee's B2C directory entry. This would be used when they wanted to invalidate an invite.

The policy would then check this attribute.

If set to false i.e. reject, then the policy would error out.